# What is the FreeBSD equivalent of Linux update-rc.d?

Tags: linux, freebsd, services, rc.d

In linux I can easily add a service or disable it from startup using the `update-rc.d` command.

I am trying to create a toggle-able service and I don't wan't to go into sed to manually edit the `/etc/rc.conf` file and add/edit a line `service_enable=YES/NO`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a nice tool for the job named [sysrc](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysrc) so you can avoid manually editing `/etc/rc.conf`

Example:

```
sysrc nginx_enable=YES
sysrc sendmail=NONE
```

Furthermore you have the [service](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=service) command to control your service:

```
service nginx start
service nginx reload
```

Comment: Cheers! Exactly what I was looking for.

Does sysrc work in other variants of BSD like OpenBSD, PCBSD, NetBSD?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a *precise* equivalent, for two reasons.  `update-rc.d` incorporates a "policy" mechanism that has no equivalent in the Mewburn `rc` system; and `update-rc.d` has various mechanisms, defunct since 2013 admittedly, dealing in run levels which FreeBSD, like the BSD world in general, has no notion of.

On the subject of things defunct for years: on a Linux system nowadays you will be likely using `systemctl` rather than `update-rc.d`.

What you use to enable or to disable services depends from what service management system you are employing.

- **Mewburn `rc`:** For the Mewburn `rc` system that comes with vanilla FreeBSD, there is indeed `sysrc` as mentioned by M. Andersen in another answer.

  ```
  sysrc -v jail_enable
  sysrc sshd_enable=YES
  ```
- **OpenRC:** For the OpenRC system that comes with TrueOS, one of the FreeBSD derivatives, one enables and disables services using the `rc-update` command instead:

  ```
  rc-update add nginx
  rc-update del ipfw
  ```
- **nosh service management:** For [nosh service management](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/) in addition to the external configuration import mechanism that takes the `_enable` settings from various `rc.conf` files and translates them, you have some choices for natively enabling and disabling services:

  - There is the native `system-control` command:

    ```
    system-control preset gopher4d
    system-control enable sshd
    system-control disable ntpd
    ```
  - There is a compatibility [`systemctl`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/systemctl.html) command:

    ```
    systemctl preset gopher4d
    systemctl enable sshd
    systemctl disable ntpd
    ```
  - There is a compatibility [`update-rc.d`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/update-rc.d.html) command:

    ```
    update-rc.d sshd defaults
    update-rc.d ntpd remove
    ```

    The `defaults` subcommand is equivalent to `system-control preset`, meaning that it takes preset file information into account, and so this command is closer to the van Smoorenburg `rc` utility of that name.
  - There is a compatibility [`rcctl`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/rcctl.html) command:

    ```
    rcctl enable sshd
    rcctl disable ntpd
    ```

    `rcctl` is OpenBSD's utility for editing `/etc/rc.conf.local`.

All of these enable and disable native services for their respective systems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like only sysrc comes natively with FreeBSD 11.1